# Opening list new form in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, list-form, newform

I want to develop a Forms Designer tool, so in list, **when user will click on Create "New item", the new form will open in the SharePoint hosted app**.

Where he can drag and drop the input fields to create different input fields. How can i open the new form in SharePoint hosted app.?

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite 'NewItem' event.

Below code works for SharePoint 2013.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _NewItem2 = NewItem2;
        NewItem2=function (evt, url) {
            alert('Hi');
            window.location.href = "http://add-in-fd360d24349d90.contosoaddins.com:12001/SharePointApp1/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsp%3A12001&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=6&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4420%2E1017&SPAppWebUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fadd%2Din%2Dfd360d24349d90%2Econtosoaddins%2Ecom%3A12001%2FSharePointApp1";
            //CoreInvoke('_NewItem2', evt, url);
    }
    </script>
```